# How to await Func<Task<string>>?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, async-await, func

I wanna declare an anonymous method to get new topic id. Everything was good except `await` this anonymous method to re-run.

My test code:

```
public async Task<int> AddNewTopic()
{
    using (var db = new MyDatabase()) //EF
    {
        Func<Task<string>> id = async () =>
        {
            var random = new Random();
            var chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
                   .ToCharArray();
            string _id = string.Empty;

            for (byte i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            {
              _id += chars[random.Next(0, chars.Length)].ToString();
            }

            bool isExist = await db.Topics.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == _id) != null;

            //if this id already exists, try again...
            return !isExist ? _id : await id(); //error: Use of unassigned local variable id

            //I've tried:
            //return ""; //That's okay. No problem here.
        };

    //do stuff...
    }
}
```

It threw an error message in line `await id()`:

> Use of unassigned local variable id

Why does a `Func` need to be assigned before? I don't think it's like this case:

```
int a;
int b = a; //Use of unassigned local variable a
```

Also, [the doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx) didn't say `Func` needs a default value.

Can you explain me why?

Comment: Are you trying to invoke `id` recursively on purpose? Or is that a mistake?

Comment: You are using a variable on it's declaration

Comment: [Why does a recursive lambda cause a definite assignment error?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2006/08/18/why-does-a-recursive-lambda-cause-a-definite-assignment-error/)

Comment: Because the function definition is evaluated and *then* set to the variable. The variable doesn't "exist" at the point you're trying to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a variable on it's declaration. The problem can be solved by assigning null on the declaration.

```
Func<Task<string>> id = null;
id = async () => 
    {
       ...
```

Comment: Nice answer! That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you!